# Why is my RODE Podcaster recording distorted sounds?

Tags: microphone

As the title specifies my RODE Podcaster isn't working the way it should. The sounds it picks up are all distorted and you can't make nothing out of them. I've searched the internet for possible solutions but to no avail. I'll attach an example of the picked up sound and a error screenshot I get when trying to record via Cubase. [The recording uploaded here is recorded](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kt-82h0DwsrTu0i_0E1lbQ6Om-6Iv6gT/view?usp=sharing) with the native Windows 10 recording app. Is it possible that my microphones' hardware is damaged? Or did I just configure it badly software-wise? The microphone is connected directly to the PC via a MIDI-USB cable.

Looking forward to any help :)

[image: the error I get]

Answer (score 1):

After some Googling, there are a couple of things you might try.

First, check the configuration of your sound input and make sure it's not turned all the way up. You may need to pull it back a little if it is indeed all the way up.

1. Go to Start/Control Panel and select the ‘Sounds and Audio
   Devices’ icon.
2. Click on the ‘Audio’ tab, and under the ‘Sound Recording’ option, verify that ‘RØDE Podcaster’ is your default device.
3. Click "Volume..." and verify that the slider isn't all the way up. If it is, pull it back until the audio's no longer distorted.

If the volume's OK, do you have anything else that might be eating a lot of USB bandwidth on the interface the mic is plugged into? [This post](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/possible-fix-for-distorted-usb-mic-audio.27952/) noted that another device (a video capture card) on the same bus apparently was using so much bandwidth that the mic couldn't stream audio fast enough. "...most laptops that have multiple USB ports are all on one internal hub, so this leads to many streamers overloading their hubs with capture cards, webcams and USB mics. Using a USB express card gave my USB microphone it's[sic] own hub, basically." Once the poster added the USB express card for his USB mic , and his distortion went away completely.

Comment: Thanks for googling the issue and for replying! Sorry for a late response but I've finally found time to troubleshoot. 
The recording stays the same after adjusting the slider, really low volume and extremely distorted. Ill share images of how Voice Recorder looks when Im speaking normally, shouting and the volume slider settings.
As for the USB bandwith problem, the only USB connected device is my mouse. 
Another thing that came to mind which I didn't mention is that the mic spent some time in a flooded room but didn't get soaked. Is it possible the hardware is faulty?

Comment: [normal voice](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Qk-Th9yZg52zgscTbsDaYHWvFO8Dgqz/view?usp=sharing)
[shouting](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lQ7jg5-LXzkV12pGIsg4GihHUhoeurjQ/view?usp=sharing)
[recording volume slider](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13dryxnG10GS9WdNajaPJK9SYGSqD1Ia2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The first two seem to be images rather than recordings, so I can't tell how they sound. Did your mic _cable_ get wet? It's possible that it's shorting and distorting your recordings.

Comment: The recording is exactly the same as the one I linked to in the original post. I shared the image trying to show that the mic(or Voice Recorder?) isn't reacting to sounds as it should volume-wise. For instance, really loud sounds(shouting) get displayed as normal voice while recording with a stable microphone in Voice Recorder. 


As for the cable, I doubt it was ever wet since I unpacked it right before using the mic for the first time. It is however very long(5m) but I doubt that is creating a problem.


If there is any other info I could share, please do say. Thank you dude :)

Comment: Some more searching on the DirectSound input error led to a comment on the Adobe Audition forums that recommended installing the ASIO4LL driver (from http://www.asio4all.org/), noting that a lot of people on the forums had found it to fix the issue. I am now definitely flying blind as I am not a Windows person, but that dialog does look significant.

Comment: Ive reinstalled my ASIO4ALL drivers as you suggested and played around a bit with the settings(had no idea what I was doing) but to no avail. Ive also taken some screenshots of the asio settings in the hope itll make stuff clearer.

Comment: [pic1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fzO3fw36IFM9lyumjGTHKHuO96Myd0tr/view?usp=sharing)

[pic2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s8apC1inodRyD-UWu38xYLjs0X1OcPCo/view?usp=sharing)

[pic3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MOK7H1xRqtcJ3Ao7cA96yzEL1vjTXuqB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: We're now definitely past my expertise. Sorry I can't help more.